Boot Linux OS from LUKS encrypted partition from GRUB
To make certain things work, I need my OS to reside on encrypted storage. My laptop has a single SSD with multiple partitions: one for Windows 11 and other for various data. This setup prevents me from encrypting the entire disk and using Ubuntu's default installation method. Instead, I opted to encrypt only the Linux partition. Here's what I did:

Installed Ubuntu on the target partition.
Backed up all files from that partition.
Encrypted it with LUKS (cryptsetup luksFormat ...).
Opened it (cryptsetup open ...), formatted it as ext4, mounted and restored all the files from backup.

However, after this setup, I’m not prompted for the disk password during boot (as with the default encryption method) and end up in the GRUB terminal instead (despite being asked what OS would I like). I'm unsure of the issue (perhaps, that's me) or whether it has been addressed in other questions.
The main question is: how do I boot operating system from LUKS encrypted partition from GRUB (if that is even possible)?
Auxiliaries:

If that is possible, how do I make this automatically, like regular encrypted OS boot?
Is there a better way of achieving a goal?

